# two similar queries with different results (one very slow)

Tags: mysql

Two almost identical queries, but one is extremely slow. All tables are innodb. Explain statements attached, but I don't know how to resolve it.

**userHits** (table structure)

```
-id      - int - primary
-userId2 - int - indexed
-userId  - int - indexed
```

**25 seconds:**

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  usersMobile
    LEFT JOIN  
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  userHits
      ) tx1 ON tx1.id=
      ( SELECT  id
            FROM  userHits
            WHERE  userId2=usersMobile.id
            ORDER BY  id DESC
            LIMIT  1
      ); 
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | usersMobile | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |    131 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2>  | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 8       | func |   1820 | Using where |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | userHits    | index | userId2       | PRIMARY     | 8       | NULL |      2 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED            | userHits    | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 238528 | NULL        |
+----+--------------------+-------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

**1.8 seconds:**

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  Users
    LEFT JOIN  
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  userHits
      ) tx1 ON tx1.id=
      ( SELECT  id
            FROM  userHits
            WHERE  userId=Users.id
            ORDER BY  id DESC
            LIMIT  1
      ); 
+----+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                       | rows   | Extra                                    |
+----+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | Users      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                      |   1042 | NULL                                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 8       | func                      |    228 | Using where                              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | userHits   | ref  | userId        | userId      | 5       | Users.id                  |    134 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED            | userHits   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                      | 238528 | NULL                                     |
+----+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: Also, if I change **userId2** in the slow query to **userId**, it's done in under a second. MYSQL is acting like userId2 isn't indexed, but it is.

I added the index lookup as well:

```
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| userHits |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      238553 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| userHits |          1 | userId   |            1 | userId      | A         |        1780 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| userHits |          1 | userId2  |            1 | userId2     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: I ended up copying all userId to userId2, dropped the index and adding it again which changed the Cardinality. I believe MySQL was choosing not to use the index due to its low Cardinality, which then caused a 10-20x increase in select speed. Not really a solution to the problem though. :(

Comment: what does the userid2 used for? probably you need to redesign your table relations.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the three tables.  `SHOW INDEXES` is not as useful.

Comment: How many rows in each table?

Comment: Please try to rewrite the query with `JOINs`, not subqueries.

Comment: What is the difference between `usersMobile` and `Users`?

Comment: Everything aside, the point is that two identical columns (int 255 indexed) in the same query were performing wildly different. userId and userId2 shouldn't make a difference. As I said in my first comment, I filled userId2 with values, cardinality increased to 1500, and the query worked. I set all the values to NULL and cardinality went to 2 like before, but **it was still fast**.

Comment: @CalebPitman mysql optimizer works on statistics/cardinality, it is known to be far from optimal for low cardinality columns, because skew cannot be examined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer the question, but I suggest you listen to comments saying you should rethink your design a bit.

By my guess it is "order by .. limit" optimization gone wild - when you check userId2, mysql sees low cardinality, so thinks that going by the defined order through primary key will find one matching item really fast, but because some skew on real values it is not true and it has to scan big parts of the table to find the value (that skew cannot be seen in statistics), where in the fast case it knows there are only a handful of the right values so takes them all out and sorts them, which is fast enough for some hundred rows.

You could try "use index (userId2)" in the subquery to hint mysql about the better way, but dependent subquery is still bad for performance. If I understand it correctly, you try to show "last" match for a given user. The solution with LEFT JOIN as described in [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) is the one I prefer in most cases.